# firefox 3.6.20 regex giving inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox3.6

I've been debugging this one application for a while and it led me to this test case. When I run it in firefox 3.6.x it only works 50% of the time.

```
var success = 0;

var pat = /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})\s(am|pm)/g;
var date = "08/01/2011 12:00 am";

for(var i=0;i<100;i++) if(pat.exec(date)) success++;
alert("success: " + success + " failed: " + (100 - success));
```

it alerts `success: 50 failed: 50`

what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `g` flag means that, after the first match, the second search starts at the end of the matched substring (i.e., at the end of the string), and fails, resetting the start position to the beginning of the string.

> If your regular expression uses the "`g`" flag, you can use the `exec` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property (`test` will also advance the `lastIndex` property).

[from MDC docs for RexExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). (See also [RegExp.lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex))

Answer (score 2):

You are using the global flag. As a result, the regular expression matches only from a specific index. After each match, `pat.lastIndex == 19`, then `pat.lastIndex == 0`, etc.

A more trivial example:

```
var r = /\d/g;
r.exec("123"); // 1 - lastIndex == 0, so matching from index 0 and on
r.exec("123"); // 2 - lastIndex == 1, ditto with 1
r.exec("123"); // 3 - lastIndex == 2, ditto with 2
r.exec("123"); // null - lastIndex == 3, no matches, lastIndex is getting reset
r.exec("123"); // 1 - start all over again
```